Fence plot using Gnuplot for one datafile
folks, I was hoping someone could help me out. I am trying to use a datafile to create a fence plot with Gnuplot (version 5.2 patchlevel 7) that hopefully would look something like this:

However, using the script
set terminal pngcairo enhanced size 800,600
set output 'output1.png'

splot for [i=0:615000:12300] "datafile" index i u 1:2:3 with lines

the results were disappointing. My output:

My datafile is very big and slightly different from the one used to make the plot I'm trying to recreate: It has 615000 lines, with 5000 "blocks" of data, each containing the value of a function at a specific time for 123 grid sites, from grid site 240 to grid site 362, without blank lines between the blocks. It looks like this:
     0.000   240      0.20000000E-39
     0.000   241      0.20000000E-39
     0.000   242      0.20000000E-39
...
     0.000   361      0.20000000E-39
     0.000   362      0.20000000E-39
     0.020   240      0.20000000E-39
     0.020   241      0.20000000E-39
...

and so on.
If I want some 50 lines to show up on the plot, like , I would imagine I need to skip several blocks, and only plot the relevant block after many timesteps, but I don't know how to do it.
I realize that there are several questions that have been asked about fence plots with Gnuplot, and I went over all of them, but I completely failed in adapting their suggestions to my current case. Any help would be much appreciated.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Do I understand correctly, that your 615000 lines of data are without any double blank lines? If yes, then index i is not the way to address the (sub)blocks. If you cannot or don't want to change your input data by introducing empty lines, there might be a solution using every if your data (sub)blocks lengths are identical. Check help every.

Thanks for the reply, @theozh. That is correct, there are no blank lines between the blocks, it's just one big block really, that repeats the same 123 grid sites over and over, and I can't change the code that generated it. I tried looking into the every command, using plot "datafile" every :100 u 1:2:3 as the instructions suggested, to skip 100 blocks at a time, but unfortunately I only got a 2D plot completely filled out.

thanks for the confirmation. Well, you need to use every differently and calculate the actual start and stop line indices you want to plot. I don't have your exact data so I will have to create some own test data to test the script. Actually, why in your output graph there are multiple axis labels and legends on top of each other? Have you maybe used a multiplot?

The trick is to use plot style "splot with zerror", which draws both a solid line and a filled area associated with that line. For a fence plot the line will be z(x) and the filled area will run from 0 to z(x). The basic format of the plot command will be splot ... using x:y:z:(0):z with zerror.
As I understand it, your data consists of 123 scans where each scan contains 5000 points. The x coordinate is in column 1; the scan number is in column 2; the z coordinate is in column 3. The order within the file places all samples at x=0 first, all samples at x=delta_x second, etc. Gnuplot counting starts at zero, so the points in scan 0 (the first scan) consist of every 123rd point starting at point 0.
To select all points in scan N, we would therefore use the specification every 123::N*123.
We will use the scan number ("grid site") as the y coordinate. In order to have the scan closest to the viewer occlude the ones further back, the scans must be draw in order from highest y to lowest y.
Assuming 5000 time increments of 0.02 the total range on x is [0:100]. To plot the full range of x samples, the commands will look something like this
unset key
set xyplane at 0
set style fill solid
set xrange [0.0 : 100.0]

splot for [scan=122:0:-1] 'DATA' every 123::scan*123 \
      using 1:(scan):2:(0):2 with zerror lc "black" fc bgnd

I don't understand your request for "only 50 lines". The plot you show as a n example has one line for each scan, i.e. one line per grid site.  You could cut this in half by plotting for [scan=122:0:-2].
The expected output will look like this (totally made up data)

